# AS3 - Finding a localToGlobal point in MovieClip that has been rotated

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air, adobe

I have a enemyMC inside of a bgMC, and the enemyMC class detects a point and reacts to where the point lands inside the enemyMC.

All works fine, but once I rotate the enemyMC inside the bgMC that is when I get problems with the point not being where I want it to be...

enemyMC is inside bgMC which is inside gameMC:

This is code in my "gameMC" class that puts the bullet

```
    pointEnemy.x = (bulletPoint.x - this.x - bg.x - (enemyMC.x * 2 )) * 0.5 / enemyMC.scaleX ;
    pointEnemy.y = (bulletPoint.y - this.y - bg.y - (enemyMC.y * 2 )) * 0.5 / enemyMC.scaleY ;

enemyMC.hurt(pointEnemy);
```

And this is the hurt function inside enemyMC :

```
function hurt(point:Point)
{
   local = localToGlobal(point);
   if(main.hitTestPoint(local.x, local.y, true))
   {
      trace("HIT!");
   }        
}
```

Now if I rotate enemyMC inside of bgMC ... the whole point x/y system gets thrown off. 
I am wondering which rotation code I should be looking for ?
cos? acos? tan? atan? I am very new to angles with AS3.

I'm hoping for some sort of fix on the pointEnemy call like :

```
pointEnemy.x = (bulletPoint.x - this.x - bg.x - (enemyMC.x * 2 )) * 0.5 / enemyMC.scaleX;
```

and add "+ enemyMC.rotation"?  I know this won't work, but hoping you guys could help me with a code that might.

Comment: Are `targetMC` and `enemyMC` the same thing?  You mention one at the start but then the other everywhere else.  Is the enemy the only thing being rotated? or does bgMC get rotated as well?

Comment: Sorry yes, targetMC and enemyMC are the same, I will edit htis if I can...

enemyMC is the only thing that gets rotated

Comment: Perhaps putting the anchor point of enemyMC in the center of the object would help.

Comment: Hmmm no,  that didn't' seem to help... 
it hits exactly right when the enemyMC has no rotation, but once it has rotation the point is off inside of enemyMC :(

Comment: Explain the math behind `pointEnemy`. You are doing a lot of arithmetic that probably assumes a coordinate space orientation. You shouldn't do this. You just need to convert the bullet point to global space: `bulletPoint.localToGlobal(new Point(0, 0))`.

Comment: Aaron - thank you so much... I have been doing it wrong for so long - I assumed you had to calculate the offset every single MovieClip to get the points in the right coordinates within MovieClips... Going localToGlobal and globalToLocal worked wonders, thanks you so much!!